# Asking permission on Android M when Min SDK is L

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm writing app that should run on Android L and M.

As you probably know, for Android M need to ask permission in the code for write\read from external storage (sdcard), like this:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    requestPermissions(new String[] { Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
```

but, I faced a problem because call `checkSelfPermission` requires API level 23 (and not 22, as I need for Lollipop support).

I tried to add `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.MNC)` but I faced with another issue - `"Cannot resolved symbol MNC"`

So the question, how can I write code to save file in the sdcard, for Lollipop and Marshmallow?

**EDIT: Project Structure settings:**

Compile Sdk Version: API 23:Android 5.X(MNC

Min Sdk Version: API 22:Android 5.1 (Lollipop)

Target Sdk Version: API 23:Android 5.X(MNC)

Thank you

Comment: To use marshmallow request permission feature, Set compileSdkVersion to 23 and targetSdkVersion to 23.

Comment: @DhavalPatel, I already did this, `Compile Sdk Versuin = API 23:Android 5.X (MNC)`, `Min Sdk = API 22` and `Target SDK = API 23`.

Comment: You can find out the API level of the device, and then put your code accordingly in the if...else block

Comment: Use  **ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);**
         instead of **requestPermissions(new String[] { Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the compile version to API 23(MARSHMALLOW)
and add dependecies

```
dependencies {
  ...
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
  ...
  }
```

and put a condition for only marshmallow

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
                        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)==
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                            return;
                        }
                    }
```

this is because the checkselfpermission method only work in marsmallow

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ActivityCompat` which is derived from `ContextCompat`.`checkSelfPermission` is defined there. You need to include the Android Support library in your gradle build to use this class.

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
...
}

public class YourActivity extends ActivityCompat {
    ...
    public void onStart() {
        ...
        checkSelfPermission(...);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but not got you. Can you explain please \ give more details \ show an example?  thanks !

Comment: The appcombat support library contains classes with implementations of new APIs which can be used with lower API levels. You can use checkSelfPermission when using the ActivityCompat class as base class of your Activity. I'll edit my post with an example.

Comment: this available only for 23, `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` should be used instead..